# how to display "There are updates available for your Custom Plugin" in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have developed a custom wordpress plugin, many users have started using it, but now I have updates available for the plugin and want to display a message to the users who have older versions of the plugin on there site.

How can I modify the code of my plugin so that once I make updates to it, it should trigger a message to the users on the plugin dashboard that there are updates to available to your plugin.

Here is a scenario:

**`Say a user has version 1.0 of my plugin and the place where I host the plugin has version 1.2, how can I notify the user on his plugins page that my plugin has an updated version??`**

Comment: is your plugin added into wordpress.org?

Comment: no my plugin is not on wordpress.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although user3042036 answer is great, and very comprehensive, I thought I would entend his / her answer with a open source solution.

This is what you are looking for: [WordPress Plugin Update Notifier](https://github.com/pippinsplugins/WordPress-Plugin-Update-Notifier-for-Code-Canyon)

Comment: hi,would this work for plugins not hosted on wordpress?

Comment: @opensource-ios yes, this is the point. Please read this: https://github.com/pippinsplugins/WordPress-Plugin-Update-Notifier-for-Code-Canyon/blob/master/README.md

Comment: This is great, also, can i show updates on the plugin page just as it happens with other plugin hosted on wordpress?

Comment: @opensource-ios I believe that this is included and works the same way as if it were hosted on wordpress.org

Comment: i checked it and i displays a notification on dashboard menu and on admin menu but not on plugin page, below the plugin

Answer (score 1):

First, good practice is to create a constant for your current plugin version, and create an activation and deactivation hook for your plugin. This allows you to check things like version numbers, and do some general initialization.

```
 define ( 'MY_PLUGIN_VERSION', '2.0.0');

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activation'));
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_deactivation'));
function my_plugin_activation() {
// Initialize some stuff for my_plugin
}
function my_plugin_deactivation() {
// Welp, I've been deactivated - are there some things I should clean up?
}
```

Here is an example of a typical update function:

```
function my_plugin_activation() {
$version = get_option( 'my_plugin_version' );

if( version_compare($version, '2.0.0', '<')) {
    // Do some special things when we update to 2.0.0.
}

update_option( 'my_plugin_version', MY_PLUGIN_VERSION );
return MY_PLUGIN_VERSION;
}
```

There is no hook for when your plugin is updated. You, as a plugin
 author, have to manually check the plugin version. First, you want to
 create a simple function which will tell you if your plugin is up to
 date:

```
function my_plugin_is_current_version(){
    $version = get_option( 'my_plugin_version' );
    return version_compare($version, MY_PLUGIN_VERSION, '=') ? true : false;
}
```

Then, test if your plugin is up to date, and call your update function (or in this case we call the same function as we would if the plugin was updated!):

```
if ( !my_plugin_is_current_version() ) my_plugin_activation();
```

Testing the update process from one version to the next is not all that complicated, though it is kinda cumbersome. Maybe someone has a better way, if so please tell me!

You can’t really see any errors when you activate a plugin, so the first step is to create a very simple hook to store plugin activation errors. In this case, we store these errors in error_activation.html in the plugin folder

```
add_action('activated_plugin', 'my_plugin_activation_error');
my_plugin_activation_error() {
    file_put_contents( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/error_activation.html', ob_get_contents());
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, but your are suggesting to store the plugin version locally, it will always be the latest rite? 

how will you cover this scenarion, say a user A has my plugin it version 1, but the place where i host my plugin has the latest 2.0, so how can the user get a notifcation that this plugin has an updated version?